# XSLT - select a node from a complex xml file

Tags: xslt

I have an XML file below where I need to get the text inside of the `<Description>` tag under the `<Checklist>` tag where the `<Sequence>` tag has the text `40`. How to achieve it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SyncMaintenanceOrder>
<DataArea>
<MaintenanceOrder>
<MaintenanceOrderHeader>
<DocumentID>
<ID accountingEntity="AT">1105442</ID>
</DocumentID>
<Description>Routine Bridge Inspection - S6</Description>
<PriorityCode>2</PriorityCode>
<ReportedDateTime>2020-04-29T20:21:27Z</ReportedDateTime>
</MaintenanceOrderHeader>
<MaintenanceOrderLine>
<LineNumber>10</LineNumber>
<RemainingDuration>PT8H0M0S</RemainingDuration>
<ActivityDeferredIndicator>false</ActivityDeferredIndicator>
<UserArea>
<EamCheckListInfo>
<CheckList>
<CheckListItem>
<Sequence>40</Sequence>
<Description>Half joints (Superstructure elements)</Description>
</CheckListItem>
<CheckListItem>
<Sequence>160</Sequence>
<Description>Substructure drainage (Durability elements)</Description>
</CheckListItem>
<CheckListItem>
<Sequence>60</Sequence>
<Description>Parapet beam or cantilever (Superstructure elements)</Description>
</CheckListItem>
</CheckList>
</EamCheckListInfo>
</UserArea>
</MaintenanceOrderLine>
</MaintenanceOrder>
</DataArea>
</SyncMaintenanceOrder>
```

I need sample of an XSLT code for selecting only the text node described above.

Comment: *"i need sample xslt*" is not a question. If you encountered a **specific** difficulty when trying to accomplish this, ask about that.

Comment: Added XML indentation. Changed the request so that is more "polite"

Comment: @RobertoCaboni Please do not edit OP code. You don't know what it looks like. XML whitespace is not insignificant.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Not for indentation of tags, as far as I know. Anyway, thanks for your remark. I'll avoid it in the future.

Comment: @michael.hor257k PS: you rolled back also some typos corrections.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: I don't agree with you about not to indent XML. As far as I understand, in this specific case, there are no significant white spaces. On the contrary, it is a good practice to indent XML code.

Comment: @PierreFrançois This is not the place to have a discussion. As a rule, OP code should not be edited. After you have successfully answered the question, you can come to the conclusion that white space was insignificant, and edit the question. Until then, do not add your own input.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try the below code

```
<xsl:value-of select="*[local-name(.)='SyncMaintenanceOrder']/*[local-name(.)='DataArea']/*[local-name(.)='MaintenanceOrder']/*[local-name(.)='MaintenanceOrderLine']/*[local-name(.)='UserArea']/*[local-name(.)='EamCheckListInfo']/*[local-name(.)='CheckList']/*[local-name(.)='CheckListItem']/*[local-name(.)='Sequence'][text() = '40']/../*[local-name(.)='Description']" />
```

Comment: There should never be a need to use a hack like `*[local-name(.)='...']`.

Comment: Thank you for the response.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I really get your question.

This will print the Description of the CheckListItem which has a Sequence of 40:

```
<xsl:value-of select="//CheckListItem/Sequence[text()='40']/../Description"/>
```

Try it here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ehVZvvZ

Comment: Hi, I am using the below syntax for extracting the value <xsl:variable name="Description">
  <xsl:template match="*[local-name(.)='SyncMaintenanceOrder']/*[local-name(.)='DataArea']/*[local-name(.)='MaintenanceOrder']/*[local-name(.)='MaintenanceOrderLine']/*[local-name(.)='UserArea']/*[local-name(.)='CheckList']/*[local-name(.)='CheckListItem']">
   <xsl:if test="Sequence = 40">
    <xsl:value-of select="Description"/>
   </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

Comment: @GudivadaVENKATAPRADEEP: I suggest you to edit your question for adding the code you provided in a comment. As you can see, code inside of a comment is very hard to read.

Comment: @GudivadaVENKATAPRADEEP I would recommend you don't use the code from the other answer. It's a mess.